# Array of Objects with Parameterised Constructors

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

Is it possible to create an array of objects of a class having paramaterised public constructors in C++? 
The actual parameters for each object can be same or different.
Here is an example :

```
class Test{
        int A;
public:
Test (int i)
{ A=i;}
};
int main()
{
Test Array[10]; //Error
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe in pseudo-code what is it that you expect? It's hard to infer what you want just from your description. Thank you!

Comment: just use a std::vector of pointer.